# How can I enable html rendering for TYPO3 7 tables?

Tags: typo3, rte

I am using TYPO3 7.6.2 and I can't use html inside the standard table element any more, because TYPO3 escape html tags inside the table element. Is there a specific RTE configuration which I have to enable or something else? My current RTE configuration looks like the following:

```
RTE.default {

    contentCSS = EXT:my_distribution/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css

    proc {
        allowedClasses := addToList(blue, button, caption, center, more, responsive, responsive2, subcaption, white)
    }

    showButtons := addToList(pastetoggle)

    buttons {

       blockstyle.tags.p.allowedClasses := addToList(caption, subcaption, white)
       blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses := addToList(responsive, responsive2)
       textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses := addToList(blue, center, more, subcaption, white)
       link.properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(button)

       pastetoggle.setActiveOnRteOpen = 1

    }

}
```

I don't want that an editor have to use plain html tables inside a text content element or a html content element.

Comment: If I understand you right, this has worked before? The content element "table" has nothing to do with the RTE. But there was a security bulletin in December about the CE "table". https://typo3.org/teams/security/security-bulletins/typo3-core/typo3-core-sa-2015-011/ The patch for the table is here: https://review.typo3.org/#/c/45281/ HTH

Comment: Yes, it has worked before in older TYPO3 versions. Ahh, ok thank you, but this means that html inside CE table is not longer supported because htmlSpecialChars escape the html?

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanted to say. If you really really trust your editors, you can reactivate the old behaviour because it is in TypoScript setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html not longer supported for CE table.

workaround 1: use html table in combination with rte

workaround 2: revoke security changes from the following patch https://review.typo3.org/#/c/45281/, if you trust your editors

I recommend workaround 1, but I think some editors will not like this solution. So maybe it is better to develop a simple extension which can handle flexible tables.

Answer (score 3):

It was no longer supported in TYPO3 7.6 + but you can also override it by

```
tt_content.table.20.innerStdWrap.htmlSpecialChars >
tt_content.table.20.innerStdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc
```

in your setup file

Comment: yes it will not work in fluid_style_content , in this case you need to override default templates.Also All tt_content..... typoscript is not supported now in typo3 9.5 you can check here http://www.kalpatech.in/blog/detail/article/typo3-customising-or-overriding-fluid-styled-content-template.html